# running a .sh script from a .bat script

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, batch-file

```
"C:\programfiles\putty.exe" -ssh username@myhostname -pw password "./script.sh"
```

This is a .bat script I have made on windows it should log me in to a linux server and then execute the `./script.sh` script, all using PuTTY.

The first part of the script logs me in the directory of username called username. Further i made a sh script (`./script.sh`) that is in the username directory on the server that should actually bring me to a specific directory on the server.

The problem here is after entering everything correctly, it gives me the following error in a dialog:

```
Unable to open connection to
myhostname
Network error: Cannot assign requested address
```

I have tested this part of the script if it works and it works:

```
"C:\programfiles\putty.exe" -ssh username@myhostname -pw password
```

But after adding `./script.sh`, it gives me the the aformentioned error.

I have verified that `./script.sh` is executable. I have also tested it manually on the server and it works. But for some reason after combining the two it gives me the error.

Comment: I don't [see](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-cmdline.html) anything suggesting you can provide a remote command to `putty` directly on the command line

Comment: I believe you want to use [plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) instead.

Comment: @Squashman i've done some more research and see that plink is the option i need for the process i want to do. now i'm facing another obstacle. does plink come installed with putty or should it be installed separately? if so can you maybe show me the sources on how to install it on windows?

also thanks for everybody contributing their help, i can't stress that enough.

Comment: Plink and Putty are all self contained executables.  They require no installation at all. Just download and put them in a folder.  You can download an entire zip file of all the [putty utilities](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) if you want.

Comment: @Squashman TYSM!

Comment: I never worked with putty from the command line, but it is a general convention, that option arguments precede non-option arguments.  You kind of split the non-option arguments into two parts. What happens if you write it as `putty.exe  -pw password -ssh username@myhostname "./script.sh"`?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-cmdline.html). You can't just tack on a remote command to the command line.

You could create a saved session with a remote command and load that using `-load`. (This will also save you from having to provide the password and other settings.)

Or you could use the `-m` option to provide the name of a file that contains the remote command.

A third option is to use `ssh` provided by Windows instead of PuTTY. I don't know if it provides a way to specify a password since that has a few security implications. But that's not really an issue since you should setup key authentication anyway. It's super easy and there's plenty of guides. (PuTTY fully supports key authentication too.)